# Instead of making database call work with current value of properties

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a project that is built with Java, Spring, Hibernate, JPA, MySQL, Thymeleaf.

My project's sample code:

Student:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Result> results;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "semester_id")
    private Semester semester;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "student_courses",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Course> courses;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Teacher:

```
@Entity
public class Teacher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher")
    private List<Course> courses;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Semester:

```
@Entity
public class Semester {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "semester")
    private List<Student> students;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Course:

```
@Entity
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
    private Teacher teacher;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    private List<Student> students;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Result:

```
@Entity
public class Result {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String grade;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;

    // getters and setters
}
```

StudentRepository:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>, StudentCustomRepository {
    
}
```

StudentCustomRepository:

```
public interface StudentCustomRepository {
    List<Student> findStudentsOfSemester(Long semesterId);
}
```

StudentCustomRepositoryImpl:

```
@Repository
public class StudentCustomRepositoryImpl implements StudentCustomRepository {
    
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Autowired
    public StudentCustomRepositoryImpl(EntityManager theEntityManager) {
        
        entityManager = theEntityManager;
        
    }
    
    // returns list of students of semester
    @Override
    public List<Student> findStudentsOfSemester(Long semesterId){
        
        Query query;
        
        if(semesterId == null) {
            query= entityManager.createQuery("select student from Student student");
        }
        else {
            query= entityManager.createQuery("select student from Student student where student.semester.id=:semesterId");
            query.setParameter("semesterId", semesterId);
        }
        
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Student> students = (List<Student>) query.getResultList();
        
        return students;
    
    }

}
```

StudentController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/students")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    // GET - /students_of_semester/{semesterId}
    // returns student_list page with student of semester
    @GetMapping("/students_of_semester/{semesterId}")
    public ModelAndView studentsOfSemester(@PathVariable("semesterId") Long semesterId) {
        
        List<Student> students = studentRepository.findStudentsOfSemester(semesterId);

        for(int i=0; i<students.size(); i++) {
            Student student = students.get(i);
            List<Result> results = student.getResults();    // this should return null instead of making a database call
            for(int j=0; j<results.size(); j++) {
                ... ... ...
            }
        }

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        
        modelAndView.addObject("students", students);
        
        modelAndView.setViewName("students/student_list");
        
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

In Controller when I call `student.getResults()` it makes a database call and returns all the `result`s of the student. Same goes for `courses`. Now my questions are:

1. How to return null instead of making database call.
2. How to return students with results for specific semester only in `student.courses`.

For second question I tried the following query but it gives ERROR:

```
FROM Student student JOIN Semester semester WHERE student.semester.id=:semesterId JOIN Result result where student.id=result.student.id
```

I want to perform multiple join operations and return students with multiple specific lists like: results, courses, ...

Answer (score 0):

I will address your questions one by one and try to answer it.

**1. How to return null instead of making DB calls**

I am assuming you are referring to related Entities which gets called eagerly even when not needed (i.e.: you want results and courses to be null until explicitly fetched).

To achieve this you can use **FetchType.LAZY** for those relationships where you dont want the related entity to get fetched automatically.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Result> results;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name = "student_courses",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Course> courses;
```

**2. How to return students with results for a specific semester**

Try this out

```
@Override
public List<Student> findStudentsOfSemester(Long semesterId){
    Query query;
    if (semesterId == null) {
        query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT student FROM Student student");
    } else {
        query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT DISTINCT student FROM Student student " +
            "JOIN student.semester semester " +
            "JOIN student.results result " +
            "WHERE semester.id = :semesterId"
        );
        query.setParameter("semesterId", semesterId);
    }
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Hope i was able to address your issues and add some value to it. Please follow up in comments in case of any doubt, i am here to help.
keep coding!!